# AngularJs: Exclude some requests from Interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my interceptor which handles global errors. But I want to bypass some http requests. Any suggestions ?

```
 var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q',function (scope, $q) {
        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }
        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status;
            if (status == 401) {
                window.location = "./index.html#/404";
                return;
            }
            if (status == 0) {
                window.location = "./index.html#/nointernet";
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }
    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to implement this functionality simply by adding a property to the config object of the $http request. ie. `ignore401`. Then, in my interceptor, in the response error handler, check for the property on the config object, and if it is present, do not forward to login or whatever else you do on a 401 response.

First, the interceptor:

```
$provide.factory('authorization', function() {
    return {
        ...

        responseError: (rejection) => {
            if (rejection.status === 401 && !rejection.config.ignore401) {
                // redirect to login
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Then, for any request that I want to bypass the 401 error handler:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/example/request/to/ignore/401error',
    ignore401: true
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: but there is no certainty that adding a "custom" property on the config object on request will still be available in the response, is there?

Comment: @cipak - The documentation suggests that the config object sent is returned on the response object from the promise.

`config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.`

from: https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 4):

I'm solving this as follows:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        var hideUrl = "benefit/getall"; // don't show the loading indicator for this request
        var hide = (config.url.indexOf(hideUrl)); // is this isn't -1, it means we should hide the request from the loading indicator
        if(hide == -1)
        {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')

        }
        return config
      },
      response: function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
        return response
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the response object contain an "options" property where you can inspect what URL was used in the request?